# what method would I use to find space

Tags: java

im writing a program that subs out any spaces with hypens. The program compiles but it inserts a hyphen at the beginning of the program instead of every instance of a space the source code is as follows:
package Exercises;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class filehyphen {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws IOException{
    DataOutputStream wr;
    DataInputStream re;
    
    Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    FileOutputStream text;
    FileInputStream open;
    
    String OgTxt;
        
        
        try {
            wr = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("random.txt"));
            System.out.println(" Type whatever youd like");
            
            OgTxt = type.nextLine();
            
            wr.writeUTF(OgTxt);
            
            System.out.println(" heres what you typed : " + OgTxt);
            
            wr.close();
            type.close();
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("cannot write to this file");
        }
         
        System.out.println("heres what the text would be with spaces as hyphens");
        
         try {
             
             
            re = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("random.txt"));
            
            OgTxt = re.readUTF();
            
            if(OgTxt.contains(" ")) {   
                System.out.print("'");
                
                System.out.println(OgTxt);
                     
                re.close();
            }
        }
         catch(IOException exc) {
             System.out.println("Read error");
             
         }
```

I think it has something to with the contains method but im not sure. Answers appreciated. Thanks you!!

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to debug your program.  Are you using an IDE (Integrated Development Environment)?  If not, then  you should, and then read some tutorials on how to debug with that IDE.

Comment: Even without an IDE, you can print variables and find out what's going on in your program. Why are you using `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream`? I don't think they're for writing text to a file. Perhaps check out Baeldung's [Java – Write to File](https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file) and Oracle's tutorial on [Character Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the `Main` method below for your solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    DataOutputStream wr;
    DataInputStream re;

    Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);

    FileOutputStream text;
    FileInputStream open;

    String OgTxt;
    
    
    try {
        wr = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("random.txt"));
        System.out.println("Type whatever youd like");
        
        OgTxt = type.nextLine();
        
        wr.writeUTF(OgTxt);
        
        System.out.println("heres what you typed : " + OgTxt);
        
        wr.close();
        type.close();
    }
    catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("cannot write to this file");
    }
     
    System.out.println("heres what the text would be with spaces as hyphens");
    
     try {
         
      re = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("random.txt"));
      
      OgTxt = re.readUTF();
      
      String replacedString = OgTxt.replace(" ", "-");

      System.out.println(replacedString);
            
      re.close();
    }
    catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Read error");
        
    }
}
```

I removed the `if` statement in your second `try`...`catch` block and made use of the `replace` method provided natively by the String class.

In your post you say that spaces should be replaced by hyphens, however you are trying to replace spaces with single quotation marks. Assuming you meant hyphens I corrected that.